# MVC5 Html.RenderAction with different controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, renderaction

I am starting with MVC5 and created first project from [MVC5 Getting Started](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started).

Now trying with Partial Rendering and added a method in MoviesController as below

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult PriceRange()
{
   var maxprice = db.Movies.Max(m => m.Price);
   var minprice = db.Movies.Min(m => m.Price);
   ViewBag.MaxPrice = maxprice;
   ViewBag.MinPrice = minprice;
   return PartialView();
}
```

It sets Min and Max price from Movies collection into ViewBag that are later displayed at view. I am trying to render it on different views.

First i tried to render it at `Views/Movies/Index.cshtml` as below

```
@{Html.RenderAction("PriceRange");}
```

It works well there and results displayed correctly because it is using `MoviesController`, the same class where method `PriceRange` defined.

Then i tried to render it at `Views/Hello/Index.cshtml` (this view is using `HelloWorldController`) with following code (first passing Action name then Controller name)

```
@{Html.RenderAction("PriceRange", "MoviesController");}
```

Here it is giving run-time error

> The controller for path '/HelloWorld/Index' was not found or does not implement IController.

Here is complete code from Views/Hello/Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Movie List";
}
<h2>My Movie List</h2>
<p>Hello from our view template</p>
@{Html.RenderAction("PriceRange", "MoviesController");}
```

I found few examples through Google, they are calling RenderAction helper the same way, first passing Action name then Controller name.

I couldn't understand what the wrong i am doing here.
Can someone point out?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

It might be that you're adding the "Controller" postfix to the controller name which isn't required.

Try:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("PriceRange", "Movies");}
```

Comment: @Html.Action does this without the curly braces.

Comment: @Html.Action does without braces but most of the time you need `RenderAction` due to better performance.

Answer (score 1):

The controller name needs to be "Movies" and not "MoviesController". Because now I believe it is looking for a controller called "MoviesControllerController".